# Tasker - "No Named Profiles Exist" - Huh?

Tags: tasker

I am trying to have create a basic Task to control a Profile (On/Off).

From the new Task:  "+ > Tasker > Profile Status", clicking the search icon returns "No Named Profiles Exist", even though profiles with custom names actually do exist.

I could swear I had this working in recent attempt, but LOST after a factory reset on my Pixel XL phone.  I tried from another device (Tablet), but get the same result.  Multiple restarts, reboots do not help.

I suspect I may just be using the wrong approach to complete this Task.

Any suggestions to proceed?

Thx!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Not sure whats going on. Did you clear your tasks to start over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And then, by no special action from me, it worked.  My profiles are appearing in the list.

Gahh... :(